# install4j Add VM option from installer's input value

Tags: install4j

Some screen of my install4j installer has Text Input.
I need to write a value from it to .vmoption file.
I added 'Add VM Options' action with following value:

```
-Dhttp.proxyPort=${installer:httpPort}
```

where 'httpPort' variable of my text input.
But as result I didn't get this line in .vmoption file.
What do I do wrong?

P.S. If I hard code value of VM option it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in install4j 10.0.7 and will be fixed in 10.0.8. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a current build to try out the fix.